# Regular apostrophe with XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm trying to get a regular apostrophe with XeTeX, like this one:

[image: who]

However all I'm getting by typing `who's` in my `.tex` is

[image]

(notice the diagonal apostrophe)

How can I get the nice first one to get rendered?

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example? A quick test file using standard settings for both plain and LaTeX shows a perfectly-normal looking `'`.

Comment: What font are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Initial remark: You don't mention in your message how you load families, so I'll assume it's via an instruction such as `\setmainfont` (provided by the [fontspec](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec) package). I'm making this assumption because loading font-related packages such as `lmodern` or `libertine` will activate the use of "smart" single and double quotes automatically.

To instruct XeLaTeX -- and LuaLaTeX too, for that matter -- to use typographic apostrophes instead of single "typewriter-style" straight quotes, load the `fontspec` package and use the option `Ligatures=TeX` when specifying the font family to be used for the document, say via the instruction `\setmainfont`.

Setting this option will also activate the automatic conversion of `--` and `---` (double and triple dashes) into typographic en- and em-dashes and the automatic conversion of double back ticks and double single quotes into opening and closing typographic quotes.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}
who's I'm that'll. She asked, ``Who's there?''

\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % Note: 'Ligatures=TeX' not specified
who's I'm that'll. She asked, ``Who's there?''
\end{document}
```

Comment: remove all `\setmainfont` and it will also work. Latin Modern is used by default with `Ligatures=TeX`

Comment: @Herbert - Judging from the screenshot the OP posted, he/she isn't using Latin Modern. I used Latin Modern in my answer purely to illustrate the use of the `Ligatures=TeX` option...

Comment: I know :-) Using `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}` or another font makes more sense here.

Comment: @Herbert - Good suggestion to use a font other than LM in the MWE. I'll modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That depends to your font setting. With Latin Modern or Libertine it is the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

\Huge who's

\end{document}
```

[image]

Package `libertine` sets by default `Ligatures=TeX` which is needed here. Another setting maybe `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}` .